# Why does Docker container exited with code 0 and does not expose 9000 port for connection

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, centos7, phalcon

Can anyone help me to understand why my Docker container exited with status 0 or debug this further. I'm trying to run Phalcon framework on CentOS7 with no luck:

```
php-phalcon exited with code 0
```

docker-compose-yml is following:

```
...
  php-phalcon:
    build: docker/php-phalcon
    container_name: php-phalcon
    working_dir: /application
    volumes:
      - ./application:/application
      - ./docker/php-phalcon/php-ini-overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
```

Dockerfile is the following:

```
FROM centos:centos7

ENV TERM=linux

RUN yum -y install deltarpm \
    && yum -y install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm \
    && yum -y install epel-release yum-utils \
    && yum-config-manager --disable remi-php54 \
    && yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73 \
    && yum -y install \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        unzip \
        php \
        php-cli \
        php-common \
        php-mbstring \
        php-xml \
        php-json \
        php-apcu \
        php-apcu-bc \
        php-mysqlnd \
        php-zip \
        php-devel \
        php-gd \
        php-mcrypt \
        php-opcache \
        php-readline \
        php-curl \
        php-zip \
        php-pear \
        php-bcmath \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && composer global require hirak/prestissimo \
    && composer clear-cache \
    && yum -y clean all \
    && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/* ~/.composer

RUN echo 'd /run/php-fpm 755 root root' >> /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/php-fpm.conf
RUN yum install -y php-fpm \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

COPY overrides.conf /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/z-overrides.conf

WORKDIR "/application"

RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.rpm.sh | bash

RUN yum update -y \
    && yum install -y php73u-phalcon

CMD ["/usr/sbin/php-fpm", "-O" ]

EXPOSE 9000
```

Similar configuration but based on Ubuntu working as expected.

Thank you in advance!

### Update

By @RemiCollet advice I have changed php-amp start command to

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/php-fpm", "--nodaemonize", "--force-stderr" ]
```

and it does not failing as before but not exposing 9000 port

Comment: CentOS is not supported with a lot of priority. You can try seeing if you've followed the **OS Requirements** from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/).

Comment: @NeelKamath thanks for reply but I'm using MacOS as a host and trying to run Docker container on CentOS7.

Comment: By default, on CentOS, php-fpm run as a daemon, so try with --nodaemonize option

Comment: @RemiCollet thanks now Container does not exits as before however does not expose 9000 port. Do you have any ideas why is that so?

Comment: not sure, i use docker-compose, to hook several containers together, maybe my config can help you https://github.com/delboy1978uk/lamp/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

Comment: And note that: _The EXPOSE instruction **does not actually publish the port**. [...] To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag [...]._ 
Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

Comment: (continuing) or using `ports` on the docker-compose.yml